# How to beat the 10 car long Southampton to New York Route in the United Kingdom Map Collection set of Ticket to Ride?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom

We are big fans of Ticket to Ride, and having both the America and Europe versions and recently added the United Kingdom Map Collection set too.

In this variant, there is a 10 car long route from Southampton to New York, which even does not need any technology cards to build.

Our games merely reduced to a competition who can build that route first, because in every single game, regardless who does it first, that person wins the game, whatever tactic (longer routes, more Tickets, etc) other players try.

How to beat that Route? 40 points in this game variant for that route seems extremely much.

Comment: As I understand it this route does need some technologies: propellers and superheated steam boiler, since it's over water route and more than three cars long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Boiler Lagging and Steam Turbines**
The times that I have won against someone who got the Southampton-New York route, I had relied on the bonus points from the Boiler Lagging card (score 1 extra point for each route that you claim) and the Steam Turbines card (score 2, or 3 extra points for each Ferry route that you claim).

**Right of Way** Also, this is riskier but, you can buy the Right of Way card and lay down your own Southampton route next to your opponents route. This is particularly nasty because you will both be hoarding cards, hopefully of different colours, which will cause serious problems for the other players who will need these cardsto complete their routes.

**Equalising Beam and Risky Contracts** These cards would certainly help, but I have won more than once against the Southampton=New York player without them.

[Rules for Ticket To Ride - United Kingdom](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/fr/img/720123-T2RMC5-UK-Rules-EN-2017.pdf)

Comment: The right of way idea is especially interesting, but a bit hefty price of 4 locomotives, though I can understand it. :)
Will try next time I think. 
Regarding the cards Equalising Beam and Risky Contracts, when I tried them, I lost those too against the long route player.

Comment: In my most recent game of TTR:UK I won without the New York route by using the Boiler-Lagging / Turbines tactic, combined with a fairly standard technique of getting a good long route (Glasgow to France), and then collecting additional tickets to find routes which I had already completed / could complete easy. On my final turn I spent all my extra cards (literally 16 cards as 4 wildcards I think) buying the card which gives bonus points for each completed ticket.

Comment: @Neil Tarrant : In the game you won, did one of the other players build the Southampton-New York route? I believe that a means of overcoming that tactic is the point of Mcload's question...

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. Yes - the second place player (4 player game) completed the route.

Comment: In the game I tried to use the Right of Way to beat the 10 car long route, actually, I managed to build it first. Another good strategy :)